# Java - Jax-Ws WebService (SOAP)

Tags: java, web-services, soap

i have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private int id;
    private Foo children;

    //here default constructor and setter/getter for both (id and children)
}
```

and one service like this:

```
@WebMethod
public boolean setTree(Foo foo) {
    //do something
}
```

When i import the wsdl with wsimport the class Foo presents only getter and setter of the int id property. Why Foo children property is missing?. The ws import is correct (no error) and the service call ends correctly ...
Note: my Foo class must map a tree of Foo object (children proprety will changed in List child).

Where is my error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with wsimport but I can make an wild assumption that there is something wrong with the naming conventions.

Make sure that your constructor is explicit zero-argument constructor and also make sure that your setters and getters are within the java bean specifications. I would also guess that the object type class should be serializable.